# Generating sequence number in Beanshell scripting

Tags: java, scripting, jmeter, beanshell

I am new to Beanshell scripting. I am trying to generate sequential numbers, the scripting code I tried is as below

File Name: sequence.bsh

```
string = new String();
Long[] n = new Long[] {1000};
for (i=0; i < n; i++){
    sequence = String.format("%08d", i);
    System.out.println(sequence);
}
```

When I try to run this code I get the below
**Error:**

**Evaluation Error: Sourced file: sequence.bsh : Operator: '"<"' inappropriate for
 objects : at Line: 3 : in file: sequence.bsh : ;**

The above lines of code work as expected in a compiled java program & I get sequence generated from 00000001 to 00009999.

I need to know how to rectify this operator error & assign the result to a variable so that I can use it inside a JMeter test case. something like `vars.put("VARNAME", i.toString());`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beanshell is not very Java, I guess you need to use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class instead of String.format() method.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( "00000000" );

int  n = 1000;

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    String sequence = df.format(i);
    System.out.println(sequence);
}
```

There is a nice [Beanshell scripting guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) that can help a lot

Comment: You can use String.format(String format, Object... args), but in order to do so, you need to pass an array for the args, not a single object: String.format("hello %s", new Object[]{"world"});

Answer (score 0):

n is an array, you shouldn't use < with an array. But why do you use an array? You don't need it for the purpose of the code you posted. You could try to change it into a Long.

```
string = new String();
Long n = 1000;
for (i=0; i < n; i++){
    sequence = String.format("%08d", i);
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Initially I tried the similar code but during compilation the same error persisted . **Error in method invocation: Static method format( java.lang.String** I have Java 1.6. Why is beanshell interpreter not able to read String.format() method?

Comment: @Rocky - I don't really know it's not working. But using String.format("%08d", new Object[]{i}) will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (i=0; i < n; i++){
```

to

```
for (i=0; i < n.length; i++){
```

You're attempting to compare an integer, `i`, and an `array` of type `Long`.

Comment: It doesn't seems that he wants to loop throw every elements in the array.

Comment: Yes you guys are correct. I over looked that. The reason I added Long[] was to avoid a error i got earlier 

**Evaluation Error: Sourced file: sequence.bsh : Error in method invocation: Static method format( java.lang.String, int ) not found in class'java.lang.String' :at Line: 4 : in file: sequence.bsh : String .format ( "%08d" , i )**


Now I am getting the same error after adding n.length.

I have java 1.6 version. Why is beanshell interpreter not able to read String.format() method?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [JMeter function: __counter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/64307-using-jmeter-functions-part-ii#__counter) that generates a new number each time it is called, starting with 1 and increasing incrementally by one.